# iOS Dropbox API: Import DropboxSDK/DropboxSDK.h in a .h file

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox-api

Importing DropboxSDK in a .m file works perfect, but as soon as I try to import it in a header (so as to subclass it) I get a "Parse Issue: Expected a type" error for each .h file in DropboxSDK (DBRestClient, DBRequest etc)

.h file:

```
    #ifndef Photo_Voithos_Voithos_h
#define Photo_Voithos_Voithos_h

#endif

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <DropboxSDK/DropboxSDK.h>

@interface Voithos : NSObject

@property NSDate *date;
```

.m (ViewController) file

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <DropboxSDK/DropboxSDK.h>
#import "Voithos.h"


@interface ViewController () <DBRestClientDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) DBRestClient *restClient;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Voithos *voithos;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)initiateDropbox {
    self.restClient = [[DBRestClient alloc] initWithSession:[DBSession sharedSession]];
    self.restClient.delegate = self;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code so far?

Comment: Hm, I can't see to reproduce the issue you're seeing with this code. (Though it does look like you're missing @end in both files.) Maybe someone with more Objective-C experience can offer some insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you added `Security.framework` and `QuartzCore.framework` to your build phase for target you are using. Probably those are missing.